Простенькая задачка на питоне с комбинаторикой
Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста оптимизированный алгоритм на питоне, который определяет сколько чисел в промежутке от 1 до 10**9 имеют ровно два нуля в своей двоичной записи. Простой перебор не катит :)

Да все просто - рассмотрите n-значные числа и сколько из них имеют ровно два нуля в записи... Ну и просуммируйте.

Точно ли вы сформулировали задачу? Именно до 10^9, или задаётся край диапазона, не превышающий эту границу?

Ладно, раз пошла такая пьянка и уже начали отвечать, невзирая на учебность задания...
Итак, n-значное число. Первая цифра - от 1 до 9, 9 вариантов.
В следующих n-1 знакоместах два нуля размещаются C_{n-1}^2 способами, сиречь
(n-1)!/2!/(n-3)! = (n-1)*(n-2)/2

В оставшиеся n-3 мест размещаем цифры от 1 до 9 9^(n-3) способами.
Итого - сумма
9^(n-2)*(n-1)*(n-2)/2

Для n от 3 (можно и от 1, обнулится...) до 9.
total = 0
for n in range(1,10):
    total = total + 9**(n-2)*(n-1)*(n-2)/2
print(total)

Как оптимизировать эти 4 строчки? Ну разве что до
print(146039364)


Уважаемый автор вопроса имел в виду нули в двоичной записи числа.

Ещё пару раз ответ перепишете и готово будет.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Перечитал... Где это сказано? Там только "ровно два нуля в своей записи", но ни слова о двоичной. Ну, переделать же - раз плюнуть, нет? :)

ой, реально в своей написал. Дико извиняюсь за такой казус :)

@d8p87, это не казус. Это вы не последовали правилам, не добавили код и пошло поехало. Теперь вокруг вас скачут три человека и решают другую задачу.

Ну, идею я вам показал. А то тут какие-то непонятные намеки пошли :), я уж хотел ответ удалять. Но раз такое дело - я не решил учебную задачу, но показал, как ее можно решить :)

Согласен, мой косяк. Я новичек, поэтому еще не особо понимаю как правильно тут оформлять вопросы, чтобы получить емкий ответ. Все приходит с опытом :)

А 10**9 входит? Если да, то вы потеряли 38263752 числа.

@rotabor Если 1e9 входит, то оно тут же и выходит: в нем никак не 2 нуля. А остальные числа, меньшие его - девятизначные, и они учтены.

А, я посчитал 10хххххххх, а это > 10^9.
